# 24 hours interval statement issue MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a statement that updates a column only under certain conditions and just for values that were inserted for the last 24 hours. Now what I'm trying is to make that this statement doesn' t affect rows that were inserted more than 24 hours ago, or what is the same: if value of regTime was set more than 24 hours ago from now, this statement doesn't have to apply:

```
IF new.report_lastIP is not null and new.report_lastIP<>'' and (SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM customers c WHERE c.report_lastIP = new.report_lastIP AND c.id <> new.id AND c.regTime >  NOW() + INTERVAL -24 HOUR))<>0 THEN


update customerTr s set s.amount = 0 where s.time=new.regTime and s.customerId = new.id;
```

Anyone can help me to achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is in a stored procedure or function? You should put that in the tag and mention it!

Comment: your time may be the issue.. try changing the interval `AND c.regTime >  NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
...
AND c.regTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
...
```